# Sandstorm apps sometimes fail to access or save data

Tags: linux, container

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. My Sandstorm installation is running on Arch with a vanilla kernel to keep things simple.

In a particular case I'm trying to get OwnTracks working, but even though keys are made and the android app says everything is fine, there are no new log entries added on the webUI. I tried doing the same with oasis.sandstorm.io and it worked fine.

I have many other apps behaving in similar ways. The Wordpress app flat out refuses to work after publishing the site for example, saying "Are you sure you want to do that?" on a page without markup or ability to confirm anything.

I can't find any useful information in debuglogs or in sandstorm's main logs.. Does anyone know anything else I can try? I'm stuck with my only next option trying a fresh install on something like fedora or debian..

Update: Moving a backup of the working oasis container to my machine yields an empty app with no data.. perhaps something is wrong with the storage? I'm using BTRFS

Comment: I'm not sure why I'm getting downvoted. Should I move this to Serverfault? Should I post the logs? (it's basically just predictable "x connected, response 200 etc" stuff)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I set up a Fedora 25 install, still using BTRFS, this time all the apps that previously not worked or had glitches (wordpress, browserquest, owntracks, piwik, more) are now working flawlessly.

SELinux is enabled as well, while it wouldn't work with GRsec and PaX disabled before, so this is a security step up as well.

I guess Arch isn't supported well with Sandstorm? Fedora seems to run it well in any case. I hope this may help anyone else running into this strange issue.